# Django - Coleman

Tags: python, django, e-commerce

I am a noob in Django and I started a project that is to have a shopping cart/ e-commerce solution.

I have been reading into Django 1.2 e-commerce book by Jesse Legg and I am looking for someone who has gone through it to some extent. I apologise that I might not be specific enough in my question.

After setting up the Django-registration and Django-profiles, the book is to show how one creates a working shopping cart and associate it with a customer. No problem.

Somewhere in Chapter 3, we create the order, status of order models and the views to load products into the cart.

I am getting an error that my "Item" is not defined. The only place "Item" appears in in the Cart object:

```
class Cart(object):
    class Item(object):
        def __init__(self, itemid, product, quantity=1):
            self.itemid = itemid
            self.product = product
            self.quantity = quantity

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = list()
        self.unique_item_id = 0

    def _get_next_item_id(self):
        self.unique_item_id += 1
        return self.unique_item_id
    next_item_id = property(_get_next_item_id)

    def add_item(self, product, quantity=1):
        item = Item(self.next_item_id, product, quantity)
        self.items.push(item)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def empty(self):
        self.items = list()

    def remove_item(self, itemid):
        self.items = filter(lambda x: x.itemid != itemid, self.items)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.forward()

    def forward(self):
        current_index = 0
        while (current_index < len(self.items)):
            item = self.items[current_index]
            current_index += 1
            yield item
```

(Thanks, vicvicvic) Here is the code I'm dealing with.

The models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
...
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    status_code = models.ForeignKey('StatusCode')
    date_placed = models.DateTimeField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductInOrder')
...


class ProductInOrder(models.Model):
...
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
...

class StatusCode(models.Model):
...
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField()
...
```

The views in question:

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from coleman.orders.cart import Cart
from coleman.products.models import Product

def lookup_object(queryset, object_id=None, slug=None, slug_field=None):
    if object_id is not None:
        obj = queryset.get(pk=object_id)
    elif slug and slug_field:
        kwargs = {slug_field: slug}
        obj = queryset.get(**kwargs)
    else:
        raise Http404
    return obj

def get_shopping_cart(request, cart_class=Cart):
    return request.session.get('cart', None) or cart_class()

def update_shopping_cart(request, cart):
    request.session['cart'] = cart

def shopping_cart(request, template_name='orders/shopping_cart.html'):
    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    ctx = {'cart': cart}
    return render_to_response(template_name, ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def add_to_cart(request, queryset, object_id=None, slug=None, slug_field='slug', template_name='orders/add_to_cart.html'):
...
    obj = lookup_object(queryset, object_id, slug, slug_field)
    quantity = request.GET.get('quantity', 1)
    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    cart.add_item(obj, quantity)
    update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
    ctx = {'object': obj, 'cart': cart}
    return render_to_response(template_name, ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
...

def remove_from_cart(request, cart_item_id, template_name='orders/remove_from_cart.html'):
...
    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    cart.remove_item(cart_item_id)
    update_shopping_cart(request, cart)
    ctx = {'cart': cart}
    return render_to_response(template_name, ctx,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def checkout(request, template_name='orders/checkout.html'):

    cart = get_shopping_cart(request)
    googleCart, googleSig = doGoogleCheckout(cart)
    ctx = {'cart': cart,
           'googleCart': googleCart,
           'googleSig': googleSig,
           'googleMerchantKey': settings.GOOGLE_MERCHANT_KEY,
           'googleMerchantID': settings.GOOGLE_MERCHANT_ID}
    return render_to_response(template_name, ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And my product detail page:

```
{% block content %}

    <h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
    <p>Price: ${{ object.price_in_dollars }}</p>
    {% for detail in object.details.all %}
    {% if forloop.first %}<p>Additional details:</p>{% endif %}
    <li>{{ detail.attribute.name }}: {{ detail.value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <hr/>

 <form action="/orders/cart/add/{{ object.slug }}/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
  <input name="item_name_1" type="hidden" value="{{ object.name }}"/>
  <input name="item_description_1" type="hidden" value="{{ object.description }}"/>
  <input name="item_quantity_1" type="hidden" value="1"/>
  <input name="item_price_1" type="hidden" value="0.5"/>
  <input name="item_currency_1" type="hidden" value="USD"/>
  <input name="_charset_" type="hidden" value="utf-8"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
 </form>

<p><a href="{% url product_list %}">Back to product list</a></p>
 {% endblock %}
```

The error I get is:

```
global name 'Item' is not defined
Exception Location: .../ecommerce_book/coleman/orders/views.py in add_to_cart, line 41
```

Line 41 in the view "add_to_cart" refers to "cart.add_item(obj, quantity)"

Thanks.

Comment: If you provide some code, people who haven't read the book might also be able to help you. You'd typically create a Django+HTML form which POSTs to a view which does the updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Item` is nested in `Cart`, you need to provide the proper scope. Change `add_item` to:

```
def add_item(self, product, quantity=1):
        item = Cart.Item(self.next_item_id, product, quantity)
        self.items.push(item)
```

Alternatively, `self.Item(...)` will also work.

Comment: Hi Hollister, the item = Cart.Item(... ) worked. Now the error is "'list' object has no attribute 'push'" indicating the self.items.push(item). Its true a List doesn't have the "push" attribute. What do you think?

Comment: List has a pop(), but no push(). Change to `append(item)`. If you need to add more than one item to a list, use `extend([item1, item2])`.

Comment: It works. Thanks man. One more error (I hope the last). Now the error I have is "PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'coleman.orders.cart.Item'>: attribute lookup coleman.orders.cart.Item failed". I read about pickling and I thought it was straight forward.

Comment: `Pickle` will have the same trouble with the nested `Item` class as you did. It can only serialize by name, so it needs to import the type `Item` from the same module as `Cart`. Since it's not top-level, it can't find the name 'Item'. I'm not sure why `Item` is nested in `Cart`...I guess to make it only accessible from an instance of `Cart`. This doesn't seem absolutely necessary or even Pythonic. Try moving that class out from under `Cart`. You'll have to go back and undo the scoping changes that you've already made.

Comment: Alternatively, after the class definitions, add this line (top-level): `Item = Cart.Item`. This exposes `Item` as a top-level type.

Comment: Hi Hollister, I am not clear by where you say the Item = Cart.Item should go. After class definitions, means outside the Cart class, on the same level (top-level). If that's what you mean, I did just that and it worked. However no product was added to the cart so there must be some graceful error handling at best.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I've never seen the book and don't know all of your code, but I think you got it right. Looks like you'll have to debug what's happening. Try putting some `log.debug()` statements in `add_item()` to make sure you're getting a valid `product`, that `items` is a list, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, also try checking the errata for the book. There's usually a link to it in the book somewhere. If there's no entry, consider creating one for the next poor bastard who has to follow this poorly error-checked code sample. :)

Comment: Thanks Hollister. I had read some of the reviews to the book and they weren't very flattering. I can now see why there is no info on the Net about the book at all apart from the publisher's site. Let me write out an entry.

Comment: The answer was acceptable and I abandoned the book. I wrote an Errata and I am waiting to see what happens. Thanks for everything though. I am now working through "Beginning Django E-commerce". I'll ask my questions on that later. I am getting a KeyError which I am researching out first. Asanti sana.

Comment: The nested `Item` class is a really bad idea. Pointless and makes things more difficult for no benefit, as you've discovered

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the book. But until someone who has read it can help. Here's my tupence worth.

The error is happening on line 41 in your views.py file.
There aren't 41 lines in the views.py you've uploaded.

Is there a model class of Item somewhere in your app? If so try importing it along with Product and Cart.